# Mathemathic induction proof

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, induction

I need to prove that $$\frac{1}{1\cdot2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot4} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{n}{n+1}$$

Here is what I tried:

\begin{align}
& \frac{1}{1\cdot2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot4} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n(n+1)}+\frac{1}{n+1(n+2)} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{n}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+1(n+2)} = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)+(n+1)}{n^2(n+2)}
\end{align}

I am stuck from here, I feel there must be someway to simplify the last part to get to

$$\frac{n+1}{n+2}$$

Comment: You have a mistake there: $$\frac n{n+1}+\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac{n(n+2)+1}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$ I really don't know what you did there.

Comment: You need to put parenthesis around (n+1).  Redo: $\frac {n}{n+1} +\frac {1}{(n+1)(n+2)}$ it doesn't equal what you say it does.  Don't know what you meant to do.  It's pretty weird, to tell the truth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{n}{n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac{n(n+2)+1}{(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac{(n+1)^2}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: write

$$\frac1{k(k+1)}=\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}$$

and now do the telescopic sum carefully.